# I can not get the syntax of this php code to work

Tags: php, session

```
$_SESSION[{'\'testingrecord'.$testingrecordsfec.'\''}]
```

this originally looked like this

```
${'testingrecord'.$testingrecordsfec}
```

but I need to add the variables created here into the globals $_SESSION

this variable is created foreach item in an array.

I.E

```
$testingrecord0
$testingrecord1
$testingrecord2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `{}` and the `\'`.

```
$_SESSION['testingrecord'.$testingrecordsfec];
```

`$_SESSION` is just like any other array, and keys can be any expression that results in a string or integer.